# How to turn off the cluster depends map zoom?

Tags: openlayers

I use a clustarizaton:

```
  const clusterSource = new Cluster({
        distance,
        source,
      });

  const cluster = new VectorLayer({});
```

How to turn off the clustarization if current zoom of map more the 10?

I did not find any props for new `Cluster()` about this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866526/openlayers-remove-clusters-on-certain-zoomlevel-even-for-same-coordinates