# How to switch off the cluster after before specific zoom?

Tags: openlayers

There is a cluster and layer that uses cluster source

```js
const cluster = new Cluster({
  distance,
  source: this.source,
});

this.vectorlayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: cluster,
  zIndex,
  //maxZoom,
});
```

I need to show all cluster element if current zoom is greater than 10. Otherwise use the cluster representation.
I have tried to use maxZoom but it works a bit differently. It hides all features on the map when zoom is maxZoom.

Comment: You will need a second unclustered layer using `this.source` which has a `minZoom` setting equal to the `maxZoom` of the cluster layer.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again: [How to turn off the cluster depends map zoom?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457313/how-to-turn-off-the-cluster-depends-map-zoom). Your question was answered in the comment's of original question. If something is not clear, ask for clarification in comments there.

Comment: There is no accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866526/openlayers-remove-clusters-on-certain-zoomlevel-even-for-same-coordinates., that is why I asked again, so I will remove the prev question then

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again and delete the old ones. Rather edit the original one or ask for clarifications in the comments-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to set a function on `moveend` event.

A very basic example code is here.

If you have a vector layer with the `id` properties

```js
const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: ...,
  style: ...,
  properties: { id: "clusters" },
});
```

then you can do

```js
map.on("moveend", () => {
  // User zoomed in
  const mapZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
  console.log(mapZoom);
  map.getLayers().forEach((lyr) => {
    if (lyr.get("id") === "clusters") {
      mapZoom >= 10 ? lyr.setVisible(true) : lyr.setVisible(false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Layers have a maxZoom property which does that automatically